# Text search in GraphDB web interface?

Tags: sparql, graphdb

Is there a text search accessible through the GraphDB web interface, like there is for Blazegraph, Stardog, and Virtuoso faceted search?

For example:

[image]

I have gone through the [Lucene connector](http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/enterprise/lucene-graphdb-connector.html#setup-and-maintenance) and [full-text](http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/free/full-text-search.html) exercises.  I see how I can write a SPARQL search that includes text searching:

```
PREFIX luc: <http://www.ontotext.com/owlim/lucene#>
SELECT * {
  ?id luc:myTestIndex "ast*"
}
```

But is there a point-and-click search interface?

If I need to specify the predicates that trigger an indexing process, I would want to include `:literalValue` form my application ontology.

```
:Mark a :StackOverflowQuestioner .
:Mark :denotedBy :MarksName .
:MarksName rdfs:label "Mark's Name" .
:MarksName :literalValue "Mark Miller" .
```

Comment: I know that there is a workbench, but I can only see the *explore* option which might be not what you want but at least avoid writing queries: http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/free/workbench-user-interface.html

Comment: Otherwise, you setup something on top your triple store, e.g. SemFacet or the like

Comment: I find `explore` handy when I can remember my IRIs, but I have colleagues who will want to search for entities based on their literal values.  I felt stupid asking a "I can't find something" question, but now I know about SemFacet!

Comment: @AKSW Wait... can SemFacet connect to an endpoint like GraphDB, or is it just for searching data that can be statically loaded from an RDF file?

Comment: Well... sorry, you're right - it's in-memory only. I never used it by myself - just read their publications. Another tool would be [Facete](http://aksw.org/Projects/Facete.html) But again, I never used it, but here at least I know that it's SPARQL-based :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To configure the autocomplete indexes start GraphDB Workbench and open:

```
 http://localhost:7200/autocomplete
```

The interface allows you to index the IRI text and the values of specific predicates like `rdfs:label` or `skos:label`.

[image]

The index will be updated on the fly with the new data updates. It can be accessed from:

- SPARQL editor by pressing Ctrl|Cmd+Space, so the editor will autocomplete the IRI
- Explore > Visual graphs by typing the resource to start the exploration from

Comment: Great, I'll try later today. Do you know how to add predicates that trigger indexing? For example, my ontology uses `:literalValue` to say that something bears a value, which may be different from its name. See updated question.

Comment: this is great, and the ability to add predicates form my ontology as "label IRIs" is right there on the `/autocomplete` link.  Thanks!